NG command is displaying incorrect node version while running angular project
I am getting below error when I tried to use npm run start:local
Node.js version v18.8.0 detected.
The Angular CLI requires a minimum Node.js version of either v14.20, v16.14 or v18.10.
When I try to see the node version using node -v, I see node version on my machine is v16.15.1 So from where ng is getting v18.8.0? How do I resolve this issue?
error-image

You'll need to update your version of Node, either to a newer version of v16 or up to v18.

No, its not working.. I tried with node version 16.20

Does this answer your question? NG command is displaying incorrect node version
